# Besteht für den Arbeitnehmer/die Arbeitnehmerin Sozialversicherungspflicht in Deutschland?

Tags: german-to-english

How can it be translated:

> Besteht für den Arbeitnehmer Sozialversicherungspflicht in Deutschland?

I am interested in Besteht first of all.

Does it mean Arbeitnehmer already has Sozialversicherungspflicht in Deutschland?

Or does it mean employee has to purchase insurance policy? I mean employee has obligation to buy insurance policy but can do it later?

Comment: The German original is a question. So a translation can never be a statement.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_security_in_Germany.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term *eine Pflicht besteht* simply means that an obligation exists. It does not say anything about who is obliged to fulfil it. So the question simply asks whether the employee in question is required by law to have social insurance coverage. It says nothing about who is responsible for providing it.

That said, German social security law basically states that this responsibility lies with the employer, so while the wording of the question itself does not explicitly say so, its meaning is really: Will an employer in Germany have to register that employee with German social security and pay the employer's share of the health, unemployment, old age and long-term care insurance fees?